# psql shell over ssh via bash script doesn't get user input

Tags: ssh, bash, shell, remote, psql

I'm opening a ssh connection and then go into a psql shell.
This works, I get the prompt.
I can also input commands like "\dt".
But I don't get any output.
As I can get output in general, I rather think the input didn't get to the remote or psql shell.
How can I fix this? I thought the -tt option to ssh already handled it, but apparently not.

Pseudo code:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
ssh -tt user@host <<< "psql \" host=...\""
```

(I don't think -i in the shebang is actually needed)

Comment: Using OSX in my case btw.